# WordPress: BuddyPress plugin: Unable to Register New Users

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

For WordPress, the BuddyPress plugin will not allow me to register new users.

I have a page for "Register".  I am able to load it from the Front End side.  I fill in the details for Username, Email Address, Password Fields (x2).  I then hit "Complete Sign Up", but the page simply refreshes and empties the Password Fields.

I check the email that I have signed up for, and there is no email notification.  I also check the back-end of WordPress (through logging in), and there is no user created.

Any help?  I am currently doing this on a Windows local server implementing AMPPS.  I have activated "Anyone can register" under the General -> Settings tab.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe that it may be a port issue.  I am not using Port:80 as is default for Apache.  Let me know if you can help.

Comment: did you got your problem solved?

Comment: No, I didn't!  It seems that it is dealing with the Port issue though!  I'm not exactly sure how to deal with it, because my Kernel is using Port 80, so I can't stop that process.